# ld linker is missing when installing gcc using Homebrew on Mac OS

Tags: gcc, homebrew, ld

I am a new Mac user and need to install GNU compilers (C and C++) and CMake for the code I am using.

I installed gcc and its binary utilities and CMake via Homebrew with the correct PATH to the executables (/usr/local/bin). However, compiling my code shows error messages regarding a missing linker.

It seems like installing gcc and binutils via Homebrew does not include ld linker. Does anyone know how to manually install ld (via Homebrew preferrably)?

Comment: In macOS, there is already a `ld` executable in `/usr/bin`. It's dedicated to produce macOS binaries, maybe it already suits your needs?

Comment: My code still could not be compiled with the ld executable in /usr/bin. Since the code I am using requires GNU compilers (because that was what it was built on), I also did not want to mix clang and gcc compilers.

Answer (score 1):

According to Homebrew maintainer fxcoudert, [we know that](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/17794):

> GNU binutils's ld does not support Darwin (macOS), and is thus not built [in the Homebrew package]

So you have to adapt your build script to use the macOS version of `ld` located in `/usr/bin`